# Installing flex on fresh Debian 9

Tags: debian

TL;DR: The error is, "Package 'flex' has no installation candidate."

I can't seem to install flex on fresh, new Debian 9 install (on a VM, if that makes a difference).  I have installed it on Ubuntu 14, 16, and Raspbian, but have not had success on Debian.  I've only tried Debian 9, and not earlier versions.

```
wmeitzen@debianos:~$ su
Password:

root@debianos:/home/wmeitzen# apt-get update

Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch Release
Hit:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch/contrib all Packages
... (snip) ...
Hit:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch/main i386 Packages
Hit:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch/main Translation-en
Get:17 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [62.9 kB]
Get:18 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Sources [71.4 kB]
Get:19 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages [180 kB]
Get:20 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Translation-en [82.9 kB]
Fetched 397 kB in 0s (421 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20170722-12:45] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

root@debianos:/home/wmeitzen# apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnautilus-extension1a nautilus nautilus-data
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,581 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 nautilus i386 3.22.3-1+deb9u1 [837 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 nautilus-data all 3.22.3-1+deb9u1 [1,710 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 libnautilus-extension1a i386 3.22.3-1+deb9u1 [34.7 kB]
Fetched 2,581 kB in 1s (1,471 kB/s)          
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 129033 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nautilus_3.22.3-1+deb9u1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus (3.22.3-1+deb9u1) over (3.22.3-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nautilus-data_3.22.3-1+deb9u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-data (3.22.3-1+deb9u1) over (3.22.3-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnautilus-extension1a_3.22.3-1+deb9u1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnautilus-extension1a:i386 (3.22.3-1+deb9u1) over (3.22.3-1) ...
Setting up nautilus-data (3.22.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.50.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
Setting up libnautilus-extension1a:i386 (3.22.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Setting up nautilus (3.22.3-1+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...

root@debianos:/home/wmeitzen# apt-get install flex

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package flex is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'flex' has no installation candidate

root@debianos:/home/wmeitzen#
```

Comment: This means there is no package named flex listed in your software sources. You will have to find a flex PPA and then add/install it.

Comment: How do I find that? I've used Ubuntu and Raspbian (Raspberry Pi), but new at Debian.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly *is* a `flex` package in Debian, as can be seen on the [official package list](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/flex)

However, your `sources.list (5)` only contains the *security* upgrades (and obviously `flex` hasn't had the need for a security upgrade in Stretch yet) and your installation DVD (which for space reasons doesn't have the `flex` package included; `flex` is on [DVD#2](https://cdimage-search.debian.org/?search_area=release&type=simple&query=flex&Search=Search&.cgifields=search_area&.cgifields=type); also see below for my ranting on DVDs).

So to fix the problem, you need to use an *apt-source* that contains the required package (ideally, *all* official packages).

To do so, add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or, if you - like me - prefer to keep various sources in different files, use `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list`):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
```

Then run `apt update && apt install flex` and enjoy.

#### installation from DVD

You are using an installation DVD? really?

I haven't seen these in use for...years; I think the normal/recommended use is to install the system via the *netinst* image, and then install all the packages from the wide wide internet.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this in about an hour.  I could only find CD and DVD ISOs, but not a single downloadable file.  Perhaps I missed it.  I'm pretty new with Debian.